Local Development with Palantir Foundry Code Repositories
I'm exploring ways to enhance my development workflow with Code Repositories, and I was wondering if there’s a method to work locally in Foundry, similar to how one might develop using Snowpark. Specifically, I'd like to connect to Snowflake from my local environment and run code on demand. I can see now that there is an available feature to clone the repo to a local environment, but still I can't stablish the Spark session.
For example, in a Snowpark environment, I can do something like this:
from snowflake.snowpark import Session, functions as F, types as T, Window

def create_snowflake_session():
    connection_parameters = {
        "account": os.getenv('ACCOUNT'),
        "user": os.getenv('USERNAME'),
        "password": os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
        "role": os.getenv('ROLE'),
        "warehouse": os.getenv('WAREHOUSE')
    }

    session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
    return session

session = create_snowflake_session()

table = session.read.table('DB.SCHEMA.TABLE')
table.show()

Is there a way to achieve something similar within the Foundry ecosystem, allowing for local development with a connection to the Foundry runners? Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

If I understand your ask - Yes there is - See "Set up Python local development".
You can clone locally your code repository and work on it locally, including preview your transforms locally.
